# Saving and accessing objects

Tags: java, object

I'm trying to make a simple program in javafx that will take in some information, like name and street name and so on in textfields. Then when I press the "create" button, an object is created with the name from the textfield. Like this:

```
createBtn.setOnAction(e -> {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUser(nameText.getText().toString(),streetText.getText().toString());
    });
```

This works fine, but the problem accours when I want to print out the details of a person. I type in the same name in the textfield again,

```
printBtn.setOnAction(e-> {

    String userName = nameText.getText().toString();
    User userName = new User();    

    });
```

I'm really stuck here, I want to access the object created only with having the same name(string). Is this even possible? I also tried to make a List and add the objects there. But I still couln't access them with a string. 
I tried to make a similar program using lists with names, adresses, numbers etc, but it was really messy and I had to loop through all the lists. 
I'm sorry if this was messy, I'm feeling really confused here.

I wonder if it is possible to store an object with a string, and then access that same object from another method using the same string.

Comment: How are you accessing the saved objects??

Comment: In the first code snippet: What are you doing with the newly created `User` object? It is not used/stored anywhere.